# How to create a new repository which is a clone of another repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a project "MyfirstProject" in github. Now I am making another project "SecondProject" by cloning "MyfirstProject" since core codes will be the same.

Whenever I updates in "MYfirstProject" I just pull for updates.

Now I want to make a repository for this "SecondProject" in github since I have to work in different computers and it will have different codes from "MYfirstProject".

I don't think branching out is right thing to do since I will never merge them.

How can I do?

Do I need to push to a new repository? Won't it affect pulls from "MyfirstProject"?

What do you do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's probably several ways to do this, including a smarter one, but this is how I would do this:

1. Make a new repo on Github called `SecondProject`.
2. Locally clone your `MyfirstProject`, either from disk or from Github.
   Then use git pull on the branches you need to move to the second repo.
3. `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:yourname/SecondProject.git`
4. Push it.

Note that the clone retains a shared history with `MyfirstProject`, which is useful if you change your mind about the "never merge" bit.

Comment: Can I pull from the MyfirstProject?

Comment: @shin: You should be able to pull if you add the first project as a remote repository for the second.

Comment: @shin: `git remote add first git://github.com/yourname/MyfirstProject.git`, then `git pull first master` (or `git fetch`) whenever you want to get changes to `MyfirstProject`.

Comment: `git remote set-url origin NEWURL` ... no need to muck around in the config file.

Comment: Make sure you have the right URL too, gitlab gives the URL for an SSH connection by default, sometimes this trips me up.

Comment: How to use git pull?

Answer (score 5):

1. Clone your MyfirstProject to your local machine.
2. Delete .git folder
3. git init
4. Publish your new project

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am making another project
>   "SecondProject" by cloning
>   "MyfirstProject" since core codes will
>   be the same.

It depends what you mean by "core codes". If it is a library of common data structures, utilities, and such, that should all be contained in a separate git repository, and you should not include application-specific code, which relies on the library, in that repository. The application-specific code should be in a separate, new repository (not cloned from the library repository). Link your application-specific code to the library code the way you would normally link against any third-party library.

If instead you mean that you have some application, but you need different configurations depending on which machine you work/compile on, that should be tracked as branches in the same repository, not as a separate clone of git repository. Have a "master" branch which contains the default configuration of your code (e.g., the machine you use most frequently, or the production machine). Configurations specific to your other machines get a separate branch, for example "laptop" branch for your laptop, "work" for your workstation desktop, "cloud" for your Amazon EC2 instance, etc.

Comment: While I agree in general, it may sometimes be useful to just copy some code over and fork your own project. The OP can always merge the projects back later, even if they're in different repos.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this might be to (temporarily) make the original repository be a "template" --> go to the repository page, select "settings (gear icon)" and then check the "Template Repository" checkbox.

Now if you return to the "<> Code" tab, the big green button will read "Use this template." Clicking on that will prompt you to set up a new repository that will receive a copy of the contents of the old one, but the two will not be linked. Then you can clone the new repository and work in that one.

Once this is done, you might wish to turn off the "template" checkbox in the first repository, but it shouldn't be a big deal if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Create your new project in the GitHub UI. Leave "Create Readme.md file" unchecked. After creation, you will be redirected to a window where there's an option named "…or import code from another repository". Choose that option and you will be able to import code from one project into the new one through the GitHub UI. GH may make changes to the repo creation workflow in the future, but this works today.